# Start/stop listener with web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servletcontextlistener

I'm using below code to start/stop the listener when the application start/stop. When the process is started, based on the user request it need to get the singleton instance of OoProcessor to perform certain actions. But it wrongly throws error that OoProcessor is not started even though it is started. Is this right way to start/stop processor in webapplication?

```
public class OoListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        OoProcessor.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        OoProcessor.init();
    }

}


public class OoProcessor  {


    private static final OoProcessor INSTANCE = new OoProcessor();
    private final OManager oManager;


    public OpenOfficeProcessor(){
        ..set configuration
    }
    public static OoProcessor getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }


    protected static void init() {
        LOG.debug("Starting the listener...");
                OoProcessor.getInstance().oManager.start();
    }

    protected static void destroy() {
        LOG.debug("Stopping the listener...");
        OoProcessor.getInstance().oManager.stop();
    }

    public OManager getOManager() {
        return oManager;
    }
```

Web.xml

```
<listener> 
    <listener-class>com.listener.OoListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
```

Comment: Where does it throw the exception? Is your `ServletContextListener` registered? How do you know it is started? Add some context.

Comment: More info please. Like @SotiriosDelimanolis mentioned and your web.xml setup or the annotation in case it is Servlet 3.0

Comment: Updated web.xml configuration above. The processor is running since we can see the pid of it.

Comment: Ok, so what does `OManager#stop()` do? Where is the exception thrown? For what reason?

Comment: The exception thrown is that the process haven't started. But my question is if I get the static instance in different class will that be thread safe?